Conceptually why can't I deposit balance < ED to an existing account?
I was experimenting with ED and ref counting of the account system, it seems counterintuitive that depositing a balance less than ED will have no effect even on a (long-)existing account, the account has never been reaped, but it can't get the transferred balance either:
System::inc_sufficients(&1);
assert!(System::account_exists(&1));
assert_eq!(Balances::free_balance(&1), 0);
// ED is 2 in my test
let b = Balances::deposit_creating(&1, 1);
assert_eq!(b.peek(), 0);
assert!(System::account_exists(&1));
assert_eq!(Balances::free_balance(&1), 0);

Why is it designed like this?
Is it possible to have a balance lower than ED on an account? How?

Yes, it's possible and reasonable.
For example, if the ED is 9 and an account has a stake of 10 in the staking system, but due to a mistake, it gets slashed by 9, the account won't be killed even he only has 1 balance. This is because it still holds some records in the staking system. However, if its reference in staking is removed and the reference count in system module drops below the required threshold, then the account could be killed.
Generally, in other cases your balance is always be greater than the ED.
